# vba creating dropdown List on variable Range

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I searched alot now and I don't get where the problem is. Other people did it the same way and it worked.

Here is my Code, would be awesome if someone could help me. Thank you in advance!

The Error occurs in the ".Add Type" line

```
Sub dropDownMenu()
    Do While (Worksheets("x").Cells(counter + 2, 1) <> "")
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop

    Worksheets("y").Range("D36:D36") = ""
    With Worksheets("y").Range("D36:D36").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                   xlBetween, Formula1:="=x!A2:A" & 1 + counter & ""
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = "xxx"
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Is the sheet `Protect`ed by any chance?

Comment: Why are you adding empty quotes at the end of `Formula1`?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The Problem is, my sheet is not called x. Just tried it, it works with "x", sorry for the mistake. The name of the Sheet has a name like "x y z" and it sais "Application-defined or object.defined error"

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it. Have to write " 'x y z' ".